# Flutter: Access Single Entry in Map

Tags: flutter

How can I get a single entry of a Map shown in a Text? I know how I can list the whole Map in a Text widget but I don't know how to access a single value. For example, how can I access the value of 'mainboard' without that everything is shown? I wrote this code:

```
Map<String, int> components = {'cpu': 1, 'gpu': 4, 'mainboard': 3, 'display': 4};
```

Comment: did you try components['cpu'] ?

Comment: Yes, there is an error saying the following:
"The argument type 'int' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'."

Comment: Your map return type is int, you need to do `map[attribute].toString()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Map` takes `String` and `int` but you are assigning display to a `String`.

Change the value of `display` to `int` and access the values like this :

Check the code below: It works well:

```
Map<String, int> components = {'cpu': 1, 'gpu': 4, 'mainboard': 3, 'display': 4};

// assign the value to the Text widget here
Text(components['display].toString())
```

Comment: Oh yes, that was a typo. Didn't copy the text directly.

Comment: The printing in the debug console does work but not in the text widget.

Comment: just assign it to your `Text` widget @Berl

Comment: Like this : `Text(components['display].toString())`. That would work. @Berl

Answer (score 1):

```
  print(components['mainboard']);
```

Comment: This works but I don't want the output to be shown in the console but in a text widget.

Comment: @Berl:  Do Text(components['mainboard'].toString())

Answer (score 1):

remove ''  from last value(display).

```
Map<String, int> components = {'cpu': 1, 'gpu': 4, 'mainboard': 3, 'display': 4};
```

use in text widget.

```
 Text(components['cpu'].toString())
```

Comment: Now, the name is undefined.